# What is the cool-down period on reselling items on the Real Money Auction House?

Tags: diablo-iii

From the Blizzard Auction House FAQ:

> ## If I no longer need an item I bought in the auction house, can I relist it in the auction house?
>
> Yes. Once you've purchased an item you can do anything with it that you could if you had acquired it through your own adventures, whether that be using it yourself, **or, after a cool-down period, trading it to another character or relisting it on either the gold-based or currency-based auction house.**

**EDIT:**  I know for the Gold auction house, there is no cooldown, but I was wondering if there was one for the RMAH. I don't want to put down cash to test this out, but I would also like to know how long I have to wait before reselling an item or trading it to a friend.

How long is the cool-down period for reselling/trading items purchased from the RMAH, if any at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there isn't one.  I purchased an item at the auction house using Buyout so that I would know immediately when the auction ended.  After a few seconds pause my buyout was accepted and the item was available in my Completed tab.  I clicked to move it to my stash, and then went to the Sell tab and was able to immediately put the item back up for auction.

Answer (score 0):

Look like the [FAQ entry](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/services/auction-house/info#q17) has bean updated, the determination cool-down period duration as bean postponed :

> [...] **Please note that the duration of the cool-down period mentioned above will be discussed at a later date.**